# Laravel Lumen (5.7.8): Unable to inject LogManager - Unresolvable dependency resolving

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

[I'm trying to inject](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/facades#facade-class-reference) LogManager into my Lumen's controller but I'm getting:

```
{
    "message": "Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager",
    "status_code": 500
}
```

Injecting DatabaseManager works with no issues whatsoever.

```
class PackageController extends ApiController
{
    private $databaseManager;
    private $logManager;
    private $packageService;

    public function __construct(
        DatabaseManager $databaseManager,
        LogManager $logManager,
        PackageServiceInterface $packageService
    ) {
        $this->databaseManager = $databaseManager; <- works
        $this->logManager = $logManager; <- error
        $this->packageService = $packageService; <- works
    }
```

Do I have to add something into `bootstrap/app.php` for logs? I don't want to use facades in my controllers.

Comment: Does `$this->logManager = app()->make(LogManager::class);` work?